# Where can I write project's version number?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, github

Where can I write a whole project version number (format like x.x.x) in a Google web application project? I don't mean app engine version or endpoint or frontend.
I am thinking to write it as comment in the class that I store all my client Ids.

Comment: I know that but I wounder if there is a specific file that I can create or include that information.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the purpose of this version number is. If it's a traditional version-of-the-whole project, it belongs in the Maven or Gradle file that you should be using to build the project.

Comment: I mean the source core that I develop and push in github. I don't use Maven or Gradle. I use similar like [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java) type of project and eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I´m not a google-app-engine developer, but I think you should indicate the version into [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig)

Comment: My first thought was the same but I don't want here for two reasons: First I can't use format like x.x.x. Second every time that I change version and deploy it uploads the new version and creates new url for that. [info here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_About_appengine_web_xml) but I don't like to confuse myself.

Comment: If you are using Git, yo should use Git Tags and Releases, if you wan´t to use google-app-engine you could use read.me for example.

Comment: I decided to use version property in appengine-web.xml as you said.